# Where can I find sample data for large linear programming optimization problems?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

I am doing a comparison of different algebraic modeling langues (AMPL, AIMMS, GAMS, Pyomo) in both theoretical and practical terms. As a practical experiment I am trying to measure problem model instance creation time. I.e. taking optimization problem defined in one of the above languages I am trying to load the model and it export/convert it to LP solver input format. Model instance creation time is being measured and model instance characteristics are being examined.

So far I have only used sample problems provided by the authors of AMLs which are quite small. In order to have a meaningful benchmark I would like to find test data to build much larger problem model instance.

Maybe someone could guide me where I could find larger data sets for the models of linear programming problems  defined in the AMLs mentioned above?

Comment: Not quite your question, but [here](https://gist.github.com/denis-bz/8647461)'s an easy generator of big LP problems: $m \times n$ variables, $m+n$ constraints, python.